# MS Access: "Like "*" &_____" criteria preventing criterita from a subsequent field from working, when left blank. Please advise

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I created a query in MS Access that references text put into a form to create an expression for criteria to look up records in a table, by either road name or district.

Others will eventually use the form so I used the `like` wild card to allow for the flexibility of entering an incomplete road name in the form.

Unfortunately this has meant that if one leaves the road name text box empty, the `like` function displays all records in the database, and does not limit them based on the second criteria (name of a district.)

Should I be using a different function or perhaps writing more complex criteria?

(I have tried removing the wild card, putting the `Or` functions in each field on different lines or the same line and also thought about adding to an existing macro to limit the query results by district name, if the street name text box was left blank.)

I have been Googling for quite some time and can't figure this one out. Thank you for any help!

**Essentially:**
The form (called `MJidea`) has two text entry boxes -

- Street (`PriStReport`)
- District (`District`)

The query set up:

[image: Screenshot of current query set up]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the SQL `where` clause of your query to:

```sql
where
(
    [Forms]![MJidea]![PriStReport] is not null and
    [Primary Street] like "*" & [Forms]![MJidea]![PriStReport] & "*"
) or
(
    [Forms]![MJidea]![PriStReport] is not null and 
    [Secondary Street] like "*" & [Forms]![MJidea]![PriStReport] & "*"
) or
(
    [Forms]![MJidea]![District] is not null and 
    [Magisterial District] like "*" & [Forms]![MJidea]![PriStReport] & "*"
)
```

Alternatively, consolidating the first two tests:

```sql
where
(
    [Forms]![MJidea]![PriStReport] is not null and 
    (
        [Primary Street]   like "*" & [Forms]![MJidea]![PriStReport] & "*" or 
        [Secondary Street] like "*" & [Forms]![MJidea]![PriStReport] & "*"
    )
) 
or
(
    [Forms]![MJidea]![District] is not null and 
    [Magisterial District] like "*" & [Forms]![MJidea]![PriStReport] & "*"
)
```